# what is the difference between devMode = true and devMode = false

Tags: corda

I am unable to see the difference between devMode = true and devMode = false. How the process will happen in both the cases. Could you please elaborate it.

Answer (score 2):

devMode

This flag sets the node to run in development mode. On startup, if the keystore /certificates/sslkeystore.jks does not exist, a developer keystore will be used if devMode is true. The node will exit if devMode is false and the keystore does not exist.devMode also turns on background checking of flow checkpoints to shake out any bugs in the checkpointing process. Also, if devMode is true, Hibernate will try to automatically create the schema required by Corda or update an existing schema in the SQL database; if devMode is false, Hibernate will simply validate the existing schema, failing on node start if the schema is either not present or not compatible. If no value is specified in the node configuration file, the node will attempt to detect if it’s running on a developer machine and set devMode=true in that case. This value can be overridden from the command line using the --dev-mode option.

https://docs.corda.net/corda-configuration-file.html

Answer (score 0):

when you make devMode as false your corda node will not generate automatically the keystore and hibernate will not automatically create tables , also when dev mode is true it checks in background the flow checkpoints I think.